# How to show output for K-means clustering on multi-dimensional data?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm developing a code to create clusters of products based on their movement in 2018 (Jan-2018, Fev-2018, ...)

The instances will be the movements per month, so the data will have 12 dimensions. Example: The product x were consumed 3 times in january, 2 in february, 4 in march, 2 in april, 3 may, 4 june, 7 july, 10 august, 3 october , 8 november and 10 times in december. So that point will be (3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 3, 8, 10). The problem is: in my code, i don't know how to use more than 2 variables:

```
    from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        import seaborn as sns
        import pandas as pnd

        import random 
        random.seed ((1000,2000))

#the movement data will be inserted below
        m1 = []
        m2 = []
        m3 = []
        m4 = []
        m5 = []
        m6 = []
        m7 = []
        m8 = []
        m9 = []
        m10 = []
        m11 = []
        m12 = []

        df = pd.Dataframe({'january': m1, 'february': m2, 'march': m3, 'april': m4, 'may': m5, 'june': m6, 'july': m7, 'august': m8, 'september': m9, 'october': m10, 'november': m11, 'december': m12})

        centroids,_ = Kmeans(df, 3)
        df['cluster_labels'],_= vq(df, centroids)

        sns.scatterplot(m1 = 'january', m2 = 'february', m3 = 'march', m4 = 'april', m5 = 'may', m6 = 'june', m7 = 'july', m8 = 'august', m9 = 'september', m10 = 'october', m11 = 'november', m12 = 'december', hue
    = 'cluster_labels', data = df)

        plt.show()
```

Theres some way that i can use the 12 dimensions in this code? If not, what i have to do? HELP ME, FRIENDS

Answer (score 0):

Well, how would you usually visualize this data?

Probably with a line chart with 12 columns.

You can do the same with k-means cluster centers.